# How to show Image Path in dialog of a component in AEM 6.3?

Tags: aem, aem-6

When you drag&drop images to the dialog, it has to show the path in below to that image.

Can anyone suggest how to implement this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your problem in more detail, please? E.g. by adding commands, log messages or screenshots which are related with your issue? Thanks.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Thing is: this is not a free coder service, where you drop requirements and other people do the work for you. It is always better to try yourself, and then ask for help while you encounter a problem with the code *you* wrote.

Comment: On AEM 6.3, hover over image shows the dam asset path in touchui.